# On what name should I claim copyright in open source software?

Tags: open-source, licensing, apache-license

When I want to use the Apache 2.0 licence in my project, I should include this in the comments of my source code:

```
Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
```

What name should I fill in for `[name of copyright owner]`? I am currently working alone on this project, but I'm going to release the source code so there might be other contributors in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can release new versions under different licenses or with new ownership attributions, which is easy-ish to manage, or you can retrospectively sign older versions over to new owners, which is more of a pain.

Personally I favour an approach whereby once a version is released under a given license, that's final. Later versions may have new author attributions or switch licenses entirely.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have written the code, and you don't work for anyone else, insert "your name" - you have the copyright as long as you don't give it to someone else. When others contribute, you can still change it later and add their names, too (or let them add their names by themselves).

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.

Comment: Assuming you aren't working for anyone - otherwise it's probably copyright your employer. In many places (eg USA) it's may even be copyright your employer if you do it at home.